# Is Apple Pay token transactionId globally unique?

Tags: security, payment-gateway, payment-processing, applepay, applepayjs

I'm investigating a possibility to use Apple Pay transactionId in defence for [replay attacks](https://www.peerlyst.com/posts/apple-pay-replay-attacks-the-future-of-cardless-fraud-tim-yunusov) across the same payment gate. The defence should rely on a field that participates in the signature and is unique.

But [Payment Token Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html) describes `paymentData.header.transactionId` as

> Transaction identifier, generated on the device.

which is not enough to treat it as globally unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test example of [ApplePayJS token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applepayjs/applepaypaymenttoken):

```
{
    "paymentData": {
        "version": "EC_v1",
        "data": "...",
        "signature": "...",
        "header": {
            "ephemeralPublicKey": "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE6jY12R9PoL7bzaC3/ibs6q6+g/cqjSkiO3GVFld2NVUA6kRlq0iJRT+XzfmGFvRs/G2qwgmWY8fKu7p6Ktgxug==",
            "publicKeyHash": "AJiEM3d+czut7s1t4QdtRBPjSOxw0D6iWSp1MUdXueM=",
            "transactionId": "f8f0c804922303decba1a8a4f7c503df1a6314e44e8db5ae7eb6b7fe0323513b"
        }
    },
    "paymentMethod": {
        "displayName": "MasterCard 1471",
        "network": "MasterCard",
        "type": "debit"
    },
    "transactionIdentifier": "F8F0C804922303DECBA1A8A4F7C503DF1A6314E44E8DB5AE7EB6B7FE0323513B"
}
```

In practice it always has the top level `transactionIdentifier` field matching case-insensitive the nested `paymentData.header.transactionId`.

And the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applepayjs/applepaypaymenttoken/1916114-transactionidentifier) say:

> **transactionIdentifier**
>
> A unique identifier for this payment.
>
> This identifier is suitable for use in a receipt.

Google search also finds [How do I process returns with Apple Pay](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204274):

> In Japan, you can also use the transaction ID on the receipt to find the purchase and process the return.

Also `transactionId` is 64 hex chars or 32 full bytes long. Which is longer than [Unique Transaction Identifier format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Transaction_Identifier). So there is enough room for being truly globally unique.

Still looking for more direct credible proofs.